# Mathematics Stack Exchange vs. Puzzling Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Is there a clear delineation between the possible mathematical puzzles that can be posted **only** here and the ones that can be posted **only** in Puzzling Stack Exchange? Or there could be an overlap?

I have come to this understanding that people who ask about a puzzle's solution in Puzzling Stack Exchange are allowed to know the answer. But in here we do not do that and the only valid way to do that is to ask about a possible different solution.

So my question is about the puzzles themselves and not whether the poster knows the answer or not. Look at the following post for example.

https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3026/non-negative-integers-in-to-three-groups

This is a non-mathematical puzzle in disguise. At first glance it seems that there could be a mathematical answer to it but there is not. So assuming that the poster of such a question does not already know the answer (which is non-mathematical) was it appropriate for the above question to be posted here instead of Puzzling Stack Exchange?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just a partial answer.

In my opinion, some questions that is well-received in puzzling SE will be considered missing context when posted in MSE. Using your example:

> The non-negative integers are divided into three groups as follows:
> \begin{align*}
> A &= \{0,3,6,8,9, \cdots\},\\
> B &= \{1,4,7,11,14,\cdots\}, \\
> C &=\{2,5,10,13,\cdots\}
> \end{align*}
> Explain ? I have no idea how to proceed.

While it is common to post a question in Puzzling SE without any effort, this is not welcome here. **More importantly**, this question is missing important context, since as of now there are infinitely many mathematics criterion one can impose so that one ends up with this partitions of $\mathbb N$ into $A, B, C$. Without further assumptions there are essentially infinitely many solutions.

I think in general our community are not so keen on these situation. Searching the recent questions with the tag [pattern-recognition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pattern-recognition), you will see that questions that "guess the next term" are not very well received. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3732264/if-1111-4-and-2222-16-then-3333-text-facebook-math-quiz), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3607759/finding-index-values-based-on-coordinate) for the recent examples, in particular from the comment under those two posts, the main complaint is that there are essentially unlimited possibilities.

Comment: Thank you. I find your answer very satisfactory.

Comment: Especially considering the nature of the answer, I would close the example question as "not about mathematics."